# Disable custom button group

Tags: html, css

```html
<div class="btngrp disabled">
   <input class="btn" disabled>
   <div class="btn"></div>
   <input class="btn">
</div>
```

I like to disable a group of buttons by using the `.disabled` class on `.btngrp`.
The input's `disabled`-state is already reserved for custom activities. So it's not possible to use this attribute again for deactivating the inputs. Additionally I have custom buttons of type `<div>` which do not have an attribute `disabled`.
Changing the `.btngrp` to a `<fieldset>` solves the issue only a part because it affects only input elements.
The strucutre of the `div.btn` elements is simplified in the example. These are more complex.

---

Solution Proposal

Use `fieldset` instead of `div.disabled`, style custom buttons `div.btn` as disabled and prevent pointer-events.

```
   <style>
    .btngrp:disabled .btn{
        pointer-events: none; /* Disable input */
        opacity: 0.7; /* Style as disabled */
    }
    </style>
    
    <fieldset class="btngrp" disabled>
           <input class="btn" disabled>
           <div class="btn"></div>
           <input class="btn">
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: CSS can not influence the _actual_ `disabled` state of any form field. At most you could apply something like `pointer-events: none` to your child elements, based on that class on the parent. (But you'd probably be really rather riding a dead horse here with that approach to begin with, because "div buttons" sounds like a usability issue to begin with.)

Comment: Thought already about to set `pointer-events: none`. This could solve my issue with the custom `div.btn` but would not prevent the keyboard focusing.

Comment: That's right, but there isn't really anything in CSS, that could do _that_. Other than a hard `display: none` perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just rename your custom class from `disabled` to `customDisabled` and assign it to your div like that?

```
<div class="btngrp disabled customDisabled">
```

Comment: My issue is not a naming conflict. It's about how to disable custom buttons via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

For `<div>` based HTML, You need to add following CSS code:

```
.btngrp.disabled .btn{
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```